# Infinite scroll ionic framewrok:Loadmore() called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic  infinite scroll to load data from php api service.

The problem is The method defined on the on-infinite property (ie loadmore function) is called multiple  times when it reaches the bottom.

Here is my code

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="result in results">
 <div>{{result.name}}</div>
</div>
<ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%" ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Here is my controller js

```
$scope.loadMore=function(){

        console.log("Load more item clicked");
   //get data from api service
   $http.get(url).then(function(msg){
       $scope.results=$scope.results.concat(msg.data)
     });
};
```

I will get the console message `Load more item clicked` multiple times when it reaches the bottom sometimes it become infinite times.
Does anyone know why it is happen?

Comment: Have you fixed it? If not create a plunker I will help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Call `$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');` after finish fetching the data from service and assigning it to `scope`.

In this case, the call should be after  `$scope.results=$scope.results.concat(msg.data);`.